# Speed up Canvas rendering in iOS Safari

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

My script is rendering a grid for a calendar planning app on a canvas.
The grid of the calendar (with days as columns) is much bigger than the screen (around 2000px width, 900px height).
Also, above the canvas, days which are already reserved are marked by html blocks.

The canvas is drawn only in the initialization phase, later on the user can touch-and-drag to scroll the calendar together with the reservation blocks.
The .calendar-viewport element's scroll offset is adjusted to do the scrolling.

```
<div class="calendar-viewport"> // <-- this element's width is small, this element's scroll position is controlled
    <div style="width:2048px;position:relative"> /// <-- this element is scrolled, it contains the canvas and reservation blocks 
        <canvas width="2048px" height="876">
        <div class="reservationElement">Some name</div> //these elements are positioned in js relatively to the parent
        <div class="reservationElement">Some other name</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[It looks like this](https://pasteboard.co/HxVBUm6.png)

Everything works fine on android phones and laptops, but on iPhone 8 the scrolling action is jumpy, slow.

I am thinking about buffering the whole grid into a non-attached second canvas, and then drawing only the needed part using drawImage to the real canvas during scrolling.
Never tried that, would that speed up scrolling, or would such redrawing actually slow me down? Anyone tried that?

Do you have any other ideas I might use to speed up the scrolling?

Comment: Caching the background and drawing it from a second canvas should speed up the process. Can we see your Javascript as this is where any changes should be made?

Comment: Hi, sadly the script is giant and spread up into multiple functions.
However, I made a screenshot of chrome profiler.
The only script that is running during scrolling is browser-sync, nothing else.
The profiler is from chrome, on chrome I do not have such lags, but maybe this helps.
[Here is the screenshot of profiler](https://pasteboard.co/HxVMAIM.png)